# React-Native Google-Signin signInSilently/automaticly fails with invalid_grant (IOS)

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

Hello And thank you for reading this question.

In the `React-Native` app, When singing in manually all is working well.

But when calling `const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently()`.
The `serverAuthCode` is the same as when the user manually signed-in. And it's neen regecrted by the server.

Client code:

```js
await GoogleSignin.configure({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'],
    offlineAccess: true,
    hostedDomain: '',
    forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    webClientId: googleWebClientId,
    iosClientId: googleIosClientId
});

await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();

const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signInSilently()

var data = {email: userInfo.user.email, auth_code: userInfo.serverAuthCode};
network.post('login_google', data, {}, function(data) {
// Yay i am loged in
}, error);
```

Server code:

```py
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def login_google(request):
    check_email = body.get('email')
    auth_code = body.get('auth_code')

    client_config = {
        'installed': {
            'client_id': '.........',
            'client_secret': '......',
            'project_id': '.....',
            'auth_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            'token_uri': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
            'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
            'redirect_uris': ['urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', 'http://localhost']
        }
    }
    flow = Flow.from_client_config(
        client_config,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
        redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
    #
    # --- here it fails with invalid_grant
    #
    access_token = flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code, timeout=CLIENT_TIMEOUT)['access_token'].   
    user_info = google_utils.get_current_user(access_token) 

    sign_in(user_info['email'])
    return response... # set cookie for the user
```

Comment: Are you reusing the auth code by any chance? The auth code can only be used once.

Comment: Yes, the auth code is being refreshed. how can i get a fresh one?

Comment: You will need to trigger login with Google again

Comment: but this will not be a silent login. for silent login. dose sending the last access token to the server secured enough?